# How to make A4 paper layout for summernote text editor?

Tags: css, summernote

Is possible I can integrate A4 paper as has css style below:

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}

@media print {
  body, page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<page size="A4"></page>
<page size="A4"></page>
```

with my [summernote](https://summernote.org/) text editor? Thanks